# Change all names to john, without changing mod names to john

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".name:not(:empty)").text("John");

$(".special").filter( function() {
    return $(this).text() !== 'Admin Aaron'
    && $(this).text() !== 'Martinet Mod';
}).text("");
```

With this code at the moment, this filter changes all not empty names on the page to John, and changes all special classes to empty unless they have Admin Aaron or Martinet Mod in them.
However, if someone doesn't fill in the name field, but fills in the special field, what ends up happening is that their post goes through with absolutely no name, as it does nothing to posts with nothing in the name field

How can I make it so that all names including empty names filter to John except for the posts with Admin Aaron and Martinet Mod in the special class?

```
<span class="namepart">
<span class="name">foo</span>
<span class="special">bar</span>
</span>
```

Regular users are unable to put Admin Aaron or Martinet Mod in the special field.

Comment: kindly post HTML as well

Comment: So, how are user filling these spans?

Comment: <input type="text" name="name" size="25" maxlength="75">
<input type="text" name="special">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can nest the two statements instead of making them separate if one is dependent on the other.

```
$(".special").filter( function() {
    var ret = $(this).text() !== 'Admin Aaron'
    && $(this).text() !== 'Martinet Mod';
    if (ret) {
        $(this).find(".name").text("John"); // if .name is a child of special
        //or
        $(this).parent().find(".name").text("John"); // if .name is unique to its parent
        // or maybe even better
        $(this).siblings(".name").text("John"); // if name is a unique sibling to special?
    }
    return ret;
}).text("");
```

Comment: Without the HTML I dont know if there's a unique identifier so I made a guess that .name could be a child of .special but it doesn't seem that's it is the case.

Comment: There is no unique identifier. There's simply posts with Admin Aaron in the special field, which can't be duplicated by regular users, so I have to use the content of the special field to identify which posts to change

Comment: Name is not a child of special. name and special are siblings

Comment: Are they both children of some element in which there are no other children with the class name or special?

Answer (score 0):

your selector

```
$(".name:not(:empty)").text("John");
```

is only looking for non-empty name spans. If you want to change text of empty name spans you should change your code to

```
$(".name:empty)").text("John");
```

**EDIT:**
In Light of your comment:

> Let me reword. |Mods are completely left alone, special and name|
>   |Regular users have special completely removed, and name is set to
>   john, regardless of anything.|

1. Mods are completely left alone: so we don't have to do anything here
2. Regular users have special completely removed, and name is set to john

First, lets identify who are regular users (not mods)
Then we set its text to nothings
then we find its sibling name and set it to John

```
$(".special").not(function (index, elem) {
    return $(elem).text() == "Martinet Mod" || $(elem).text() == "Admin Aaron";
}).text('').siblings('span.name').text('John');
```

Comment: this would work if the mods name field wasn't empty
Mods only have their name in the special class. 
Their name span output is <span class="name"></span>

Comment: I don't get it.. is it name or is it special?

Comment: A regular user can have foo(bar) (bar) being  the special field.  They can also have (bar), foo, and John doe (if they don't put anything in either input)  Mods, on the other hand, when mod posting, have (modspecial)  with <span class="name"></span> being the html output of the name field.  Currently, the code I have doesn't do anything to posts with completely blank namefields. This is an aesthetic problem for the filter, as it is possible for a post to have no name and no special (due to only having a special input). Only mod posts should have a blank name field after the filter runs.

Comment: Let me reword.
|Mods are completely left alone, special and name|           
|Regular users have special completely removed, and name is set to john, regardless of anything.|